# Domain not valid for whois lookup yet still live .co.sz Swaziland

Tags: dns, domain-name, whois, tld

I tried to do a lookup on a domain I manage in Swaziland 'ngwenyaglass.co.sz' and I came up against the following error on whois.com

```
Invalid domain name...

We are unable to perform a lookup for ngwenyaglass.co.sz. It appears to be an 
invalid or unsupported domain extension.
```

This seems to be the case for all co.sz and .sz tlds here in Swaziland.
All of the following sites give similar errors that I have never seen before.

```
https://www.whois.net
https://www.whois.com/whois/ngwenyaglass.co.sz
https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=ngwenyaglass.co.sz
https://www.godaddy.com/whois
https://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp
```

Can anyone shed any light on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different DNS names / trees are managed by different institutions. Each is responsible for both primary DNS and related services as WHOIS. DNS lookup is standard and practically must be, but WHOIS is not as much, so some domains may not work with different clients/services.

A quick search for swaziland specific whois
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=swaziland+whois
leads to e.g.
https://domain-records-lookup.com/whois/ngwenyaglass.co.sz
which seems to work, listing Mr. Nkambule as a contact. EDIT: But they don't have correct information, see comment below by **grawity**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had never seen this before. And thanks for finding a place that does list SZ domains. Strangely all SZ domains I checked were listed with Mr Nkambule. Registering these domains here is not straight forward either.

Comment: That's actually the person in charge of the `SZ` TLD itself. Those whois websites don't have any special source of information; they just keep chopping off subdomains until there's a result.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the `sz` TLD does not have a public WHOIS server.

There is neither a "whois:" entry in [whois -h whois.iana.org SZ](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/sz.html), nor an address at `sz.whois-servers.net`, nor a mention of WHOIS at the [registrar](http://www.sispa.org.sz/).